# Confidence interval of transformed random variable

Tags: confidence-interval, delta-method

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. I can construct a level-$\alpha$ confidence interval for $X$ as $(X-q\sigma, X+q\sigma)$, where $q=\Phi^{-1}(\alpha/2)$ and $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF.

I have a quantity of interest which is a transformation of $X$ (denote it $Y=f(X)$), and I want to find a level-$\alpha$ confidence interval for $Y$.

I have thought of two methods to do this:

1. Write the confidence interval of $Y$ as $\left(f(X-q\sigma), f(X+q\sigma)\right)$.
2. Use the Delta method to approximate the variance of $Y$ and write the confidence interval of $Y$ as $\left(Y-q\sqrt{\widehat{Var}(Y)}, Y+q\sqrt{\widehat{Var}(Y)}\right)$.

Is method 1 correct? I don't think that they can both be correct.

Does it make a difference if $f$ is one-to-one?

Comment: I think you have significant problems at the outset, because your confidence interval is unlikely to have its intended level unless $X$ has a Normal distribution.  For other distributions it may have (drastically) different levels.

Comment: You might consider getting the confidence intervals by bootstrap.  There are different  methods.  You might start by looking at the percentile method, and then bias-corrected percentile methods.  Note, however, that there are assumptions underlying these processes.

Comment: Also, see [this current Cross Validated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/443198/does-the-log-transformation-on-the-data-affect-the-confidence-intervals)

Comment: @whuber I have updated the problem to make $X$ normally distributed